# htaccess redirect to https if https is original destination

Tags: .htaccess

Currently I have:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.com [NC]

RewriteRule (.*) http://www.site.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

When I visit `https://site.com` I would like to be redirected to `https://www.site.com`.
Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you're looking for to force https:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I only want to force https if the user enters the site on https, any ideas?

Comment: change `off` in that code to `on`, but I don't see why you'd need this functionality, maybe your problem lies elsewhere?

Comment: How do I add your cond and rule to my existing cond and rule?

Comment: @jroberts I think they should go above your other rules, but I couldn't possibly know for sure.